# Error while building after updating flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, android-studio, dart, updates

After updating Flutter and Dart, building app fails due to following error.

> Error (Xcode):
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_screenutil-5.6.0/lib/src/screen_util.dar t:58:5: Error: Type 'FlutterWindow' not found.

2 apps have same error, and it worked before updating.
Other collaborator also has error after updating, but different point:

> Error(Xcode): .... firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not
> found:'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'

Since We have different error, code or packages might not be the problem.

I tried 'flutter clean', 'clean build folder @Xcode', 'pod repo update', but still error exists.

It is very thankful if you have any solutions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by changing flutter channel to stable. Type 'flutter channel' to know which branch you are currently using.
Type in terminal: 'flutter channel stable', then 'flutter upgrade'

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment.
It worked! I changed flutter channel from master to stable as you said, and error was gone. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading to the latest version of packages
of flutter_screenutil

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`FlutterWindow` API is deprecated.

Now if you are using the flutter master channel. Then edit the source code by changing the type `FlutterWindow` to `FlutterView` in all the dart files which shows the error